# Storybook file does not import corresponding .vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, storybook

### Summery

I want to import vue file(`component/index.vue`) in storybook file(`component/index.stories.ts`).
But it is compile error and cannot be imported.

`component/index.stories.ts`

```js
import Test from '~/components/test/index.vue' # <- compile error.

export default {
  title: 'Test'
}

export const TestWebsite = () => '<Test />'
```

Here is the directory.

```
project
  ├ pages
  │  └ index.vue
  ├ components
  │  ├ test
  │  │  ├ index.vue
  .  .  └ index.stories.ts
  .  .
```

I want to know how to resolve this compile error and success to run Storybook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating index.d.ts, I can import .vue file and success to dispay on Storybook.

`index.d.ts`

```js
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  const _default: Vue
  export default _default
}
```

`index.stories.ts`

```js
import Test from './index.vue'

export default {
  component: Test,
  title: 'Components/Test'
}

export const Primary = () => ({
  components: { Test },
  template: '<Test />'
})
```